# Filter out null value from array in React

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, filter

I want to skip all null value from array in React
This is a part of my code.
I've added filter before map function but it looks not working.

```
componentDidMount(){
        client.getEntries({content_type:'formRequest'}).then(response => {
            this.setState({qoutes: response.items});
        }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        });
    }

render(){

        const user = "name";
        const qoutes = this.state.qoutes
        .filter(i => i !== null)
        .map((qoute, i) => 
        user === qoute.fields.user || user === qoute.fields.company ?
        <QoutesListItem id={i} key={i} qoute={qoute} />
        : null)

        return(<div>{qoutes}<div>)
```

[image]

I tried to make function like this, but it does not work as well

```
const qoutes = this.state.qoutes.filter((qoutes)=>{
    if(qoutes !== null ) {
      return qoutes;
    }}).map((qoute, i) =>
```

How can I avoid null value and get available data (in my case only three objects)

Comment: The filter is correct but you are returning `null` for some cases in the next `map`. Can your `null` elements come from that?

Comment: not sure. The logic is if user equal one of the fields then show it, and I get three element on the page

Comment: maybe you are right ... but I don't know how to fix it. For ex, if the name is not correct I get 14 nulls ...

Comment: Do another filter after the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the results again to remove the `null` elements from the second map:

```js
render(){
  const user = "name";
  const qoutes = this.state.qoutes
    .filter(q => !!q)
    .map((qoute, i) => 
        user === qoute.fields.user || user === qoute.fields.company ?
          <QoutesListItem id={i} key={i} qoute={qoute} />
          : 
          null)
    .filter(q => !!q) // Filter falsy values

  return(<div>{qoutes}<div>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do both conditional checks in a single reduce pass. If the quote is truthy **and** the fields has a match user or company for user, push the JSX into result array.

```
const qoutes = this.state.qoutes.reduce(
  (quotes, quote, i) => {
    if (
      quote &&
      quote.fields &&
      (user === quote.fields.user || user === quote.fields.company)
    ) {
      quotes.push(<QoutesListItem id={i} key={i} qoute={quote} />);
    }
    return quotes;
  },
  [] // initial empty quotes result array
);
```

```js
const quotes = [null, null, null, {
  fields: {
    user: 'name'
  }
}, null, {
  fields: {
    company: 'name'
  }
}];

const user = "name";

const quotesRes = quotes.reduce(
  (quotes, quote, i) => {
    if (
      quote &&
      quote.fields &&
      (user === quote.fields.user || user === quote.fields.company)
    ) {
      quotes.push(`<QoutesListItem id={${i}} key={${i}} qoute={${quote.fields.user || quote.fields.company}} />`);
    }
    return quotes;
  }, [] // initial empty quotes result array
);

console.log(quotesRes);
```

FYI, anytime you see map/filter or filter/map should be a good indication to use a reduce function.

Comment: @Vova You've a spelling typo, "qoute" vs "quote", that I copy/pasted by mistake. I've tried correcting them in my answer.